# Convert URL hack button to something that works with LEX

Tags: lightning, urlhacking

We have a URL hack button that sits on the account object and, when pressed, clones the existing account record, adjusts the record type and adds the initial account record as a parent account and opens in the editing screen so the user can make whatever changes are necessary.  Unfortunately this button can't be used in LEX and the quick actions that Salesforce recommend as replacements for this don't work either as you don't get the formula editor when trying to set predefined values so you can't set the picklist fields to reference the original account value.

Does anyone have any suggestions that will work in LEX that will fit my use case?  I'm having trouble finding a solution

Comment: there could be other ways.. but 1 option is to create a pass thru component that can be opened from the action which can create the new record with your logic and then transfer to new account edit page

Comment: Lightning quick actions is your solution - you can attache a server side apex class to the lightning component that would do all the server side work, and open the edit page of the newly created record when finished with this:[force:recordEdit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordEdit.htm)